# Android Studio: Can I still use HOLO Light DatePicker with appcompat theme in manifest?

Tags: android, datepicker, manifest, toolbar, android-appcompat

I recently started customizing the toolbar in my app and my manifest application section looks like this..

```
  <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I added this code to my mainactivity java....

```
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

and this to my main xml file...

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#0277bd"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Prior to adding this, my HOLO light spinner style datepicker was showing up. Now the green calendar shows up for the datepicker. I am guessing it has everything to do with the manifest addition of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar which I believe is necessary for my custom toolbar but is there a work around to keep my spinner style HOLO light datepicker?

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I researched and found out to add this code to my style file:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#42a5f5</item>
 </style>
```

I did not get the HALO light dialog for the DatePicker but I was able to use the new calender which I like and change the color to match the theme of my app. I know that no one answered or responded to my question but I thought I would post the answer I came up with in case anyone sees this question and has the same issue.